# How to forbid ssh server to autostart on boot

Tags: autostart, openssh

I installed openssh-server,it will start ssh server on boot automatic.But I don't want that.How to forbid ssh server to autostart on boot?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable `sshd` from starting at boot with command

```
sudo systemctl disable sshd.service
```

Edit 1

Rename `/etc/init/sshd.conf` to `/etc/init/sshd.conf.disabled`.

```
sudo mv /etc/init/sshd.conf /etc/init/sshd.conf.disabled
```

Edit 2

Or you can try command

```
sudo update-rc.d sshd disable
```

Comment: I tried it , but got an error: `systemctl: command not found`.

Comment: @yixiao What ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: You have my edit 1. Try with that

Comment: @Ziazis ubuntu14.04, while `systemctl` are used from ubuntu15

Comment: @2707974 thanks, but there is no file name /etc/init/sshd.conf. I will try /etc/init/ssh.conf.and I just don't want it to run automatic,but your suggestion make it be not startable. Thanks anyway.

Comment: How do you want to use ssh, what are you going to do with it?